# The entity with name <entityName> was not found in the MetadataCache

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Following a Microsoft hands-on lab for Dynamics CRM 2011, I am attempting to add a custom view  to a form that responds 'onchange' to a particular property. Here is my function to add the custom view:

```
function HandleOnChangeDVMInformationLookup()
{
var locAttr = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_referringdvm");

if (locAttr.getValue() != null)
{
    var dvmId = locAttr.getValue()[0].id;

    var viewDisplayName = "DVM Information";
    var viewIsDefault = true;

    var fetchXml  = '<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"><entity name="dvminformation"><attribute name="dvminformation_id"/><attribute name="dvminformation_name"/><attribute name="new_firstname"/><attribute name="new_lastname"/><filter type="and"><condition attribute="id" operator="eq"  value="' +dvmId +'"/></filter></entity></fetch>';

    var layoutXml = '<grid name="resultset" object="10001" jump="dvminformation_name" select="1" icon="1" preview="1"><row name="result" id="dvminformation_id"><cell name="dvminformation_name" width="300" /><cell name="new_firstname" width="125"/></row></grid>';

    var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_dvm_information");
    control.addCustomView("62e0ee43-ad05-407e-9b0b-bf1f821c710e", "dvminformation", viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, viewIsDefault );
}
}
```

Upon changing the selected 'dvm' in the form and triggering this function I receive the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The entity with a name = 'dvminformation' was not found in the MetadataCache.Detail: 
>   
>     -2147217150
>     
>     The entity with a name = 'dvminformation' was not found in the MetadataCache.
>     2013-06-10T22:01:49.4392114Z

Is 'dvminformation' not the entity name I just defined in the XML? Am I missing a step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unlikely that `dvminformation` is a real entity name. Are you sure there is an entity that exists with that name?

Open the solution and look for the entity, then check its schema name.

If its a custom entity they usually have the format of `prefix_name`, e.g. `new_timeline`, `new_alert`, in your case it might just be `dvm_information`. If `dvm` is your solution prefix.

Only system entity have a name without an underscore, e.g. `contact`, `account`, `incident` and `dvminformation` doesn't look like a system entity to me.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize that 'entity name' was an EXISTING entity, changed it to an existing entity and it works. No error now, but I see no data. Could you explain what type of field/control I should be adding the custom view to..(ie. how should I define 'new_dvm_information' in my form.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message with the customerAddress entity.
Turns out I referenced the entity as `"customerAddress"` (note the camel case).

But CRM wants logical names of entities and attributes in all lower case. So `"customeraddress"` did work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are connecting to correct org (web.config?) 
[See](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/208316)